# validation of hidden elements zend form

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

In my view, I am setting the visibility of few of my form elements to none using jquery (practically by calling the fadeIn and fadeOut methods). The problem is that because of hiding these elements, the validation is not performed on the hidden elements anymore. Any idea how can I persist the validation checking while the element is hidden (or folded)?

Comment: It is not clear if you are talking about javascript validation in client or `Zend_Form::isValid()` on server. Server validation should not be impacted by the css visiblity (display: none;)

Comment: I am talking about javascript validation.

Comment: Depends on how you're performing the validation in JS. Any code to show?

Comment: No, I am not performing the validation in JS... Its Zend's default validation that takes place normally... I just set the required property to true at the time of creating the form element and the rest is done by Zend...

Answer (score 0):

you can't perform validation on non visible elements because they're not even submitted with the form.

Maybe you use hidden inputs instead and perform some filling when the form submit event occurs